# Good design patterns for multiple function outputs

Tags: python

If you are incrementally designing a function that could have variable number of outputs, what is the best way to design that function? E.g.

```
def function(input):
    return output1, output2, ...
```

or

```
def function(input):
    return dict(output1=...)
```

In both cases, you need a bunch of if statements to sort through and utilize the outputs; the difference is where the if statements are used (within function or outside of the function over the dictionary). I am not sure what principle to use to decide on what to do.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: How do you want to call this? Write a unit test to see what the calling code looks like, and use that to guide you.

Comment: I find it a very common occurrence in designing programs. The requirements or problem understanding constantly change, and you may need increasing number of outputs. For example, a function that controls a robot could output the actions for the robot, but as you continue to design the robot you need diagnostics information such as velocity, extra sensor data etc

Comment: @user3180 from what you describe, it rather sounds like an XY problem, where "velocity" and other data should rather be attributes on a ``robot`` class instance, rather than return values of a random function.

Comment: Why should a function that controls a robot return anything?

Comment: A controller takes in state and returns actions. But we may also need to do a lot of additional things beyond taking actions, which are not known apriori. This is a general observation about incrementally designing functions, you often do not know the required number of outputs apriori - it is often increasing as you figure out whats needed for the problem

Answer (score 0):

If you need to return multiple things, it means the function is either complex and you should break it down, or you need an object with attributes that is "processed" in the function. A dict is a standard object, but you can also create your own, depends if you want to go more the OOP way or the functional/procedural way